# Wird "gnädige Frau" noch verwendet?

Tags: word-usage

In Bücher und Filme aus der ersten Hälfte des 20. Jahrhunderts siehe oder höre ich manchmal die Anrede "gnädige Frau".  Ich dachte, dass sei ganz verschwunden, aber laut [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=gn%C3%A4dige+Frau&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=8&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cgn%C3%A4dige%20Frau%3B%2Cc0) scheint es noch zu geben.  Ich weiß aber nicht, wie zuverlässig das ist:

[image: ngram for gnädige Frau]

Inwiefern wird "gnädige Frau" heute noch verwendet (ohne dass es ironisch oder humoristisch gemeint ist)?

Comment: Das reicht zwar nicht ganz für eine Antwort, aber dass ein Wort oder eine Wortwendung auf Ngram auftaucht heißt noch lange nicht dass sie auch im Alltag gebräuchlich ist. So ist es natürlich nicht unüblich diese Anrede in Romanen, Theaterstücken oder Filmen deren Handlungen im 19. oder Anfangs des 20. Jahrhunderts stattfinden zu finden, und abgesehen davon werden solche Floskeln auch gerne ironisch verwendet.

Comment: @Cubic Genau darum beantwortet die Ngram-Grafik nicht meine eigene Frage :)

Comment: Eine belastbare Antwort habe ich nicht. Da ich mich nur in meinem sozialen Milieu "auskenne", kann ich nicht ausschließen = daran glauben, dass in anderen "tradierteren" sozialen Milieus - das Klischee sagt "der reiche Adel" - es noch verwendet wird.

Answer (score 5):

Zitat aus Wikipedia: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6flichkeitsform

> Anreden wie „Gnädiger Herr“ oder „Gnädige Frau“ sind in direkter Zweier-Rede seit etwa Mitte des zwanzigsten Jahrhunderts in Deutschland kaum noch in Verwendung, in Österreich zumindest abnehmend. Am ehesten hört man diese Anreden heute noch auf exklusiven Veranstaltungen. Zudem wird „Gnädige Frau“ (mangels einer guten Alternative) manchmal verwendet, wenn man das Wort an eine einzelne Dame einer Zuhörergruppe richtet (z. B. „Bitte, gnädige Frau“; eine etwas prosaischere Alternative ist „Bitte, meine Dame“). In der Schweiz sind diese Anreden praktisch unbekannt; dafür werden die etwa gleichwertigen französischen Formen Madame und (etwas seltener) Monsieur verwendet.

Comment: Statt "Bitte, meine Dame" ist auch, etwas zurückhaltender, "Bitte, die Dame" in Gebrauch.